# create postgresql trigger or function to delete old data from one table and insert into alias table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, database-trigger

In PostgreSQL i want to create function and trigger which can delete old data of before 8 day from A table(which contain many rows) and insert this data into one new alias table. and i want to execute this trigger everyday.

Comment: try `begin; insert into at select ..where ts < now() - '8 days'::interval; delete from t where ts < now() - '8 days'::interval; end;`

Comment: i want to delete data from table table A and insert same deleted data into another table B.

Comment: of before 8 days

Comment: can you please tell this in details

Comment: yes I could. Can you please tell what you need in details?

Comment: i have one table A which is created beore one year.it contain lots of transavtion log so i want to create another alias one table B as backup which contian data of all data of A.

Comment: and after that i want create create one function or trigger which can keep data of before 8 days in in mian table and that deleted data on table B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**historical table creation**:

```
create table b as select * from a where false;
```

**moving data**

```
begin; 
  insert into b select * from a where ts < (now() - '8 days'::interval); 
  delete from a where ts < (now() - '8 days'::interval); 
end;
```

**scheduling**

1. create a file a.sql and put the above transaction to it
2. add to cron `psql -f a.sql`

**notes**
creating trigger that will delete data on each statement is a bad idea

Comment: OK Thank you i wiil chwck and revert you back.

Comment: if i run this trigger everyday is table b contaning all refersh data of table A.

Comment: and why you this notes creating trigger that will delete data on each statement is a bad idea. what is its effects